# Chrome App messaging and 'loadstop' vs. .load() timing

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome App with webviews.  Pages intended for the webviews may also run in a regular browser.  If inside a webview, pages send messages to the main App, but apparently they need to get a message from the App first, in order to know where to send their messages.

No problem - the main App sends a message as soon as it sees a 'loadstop' event which tells the pages where to send messages to.  If a page is not in a webview then it never gets the message.

The problem is, I need to know when a page should stop waiting for the message and assume it is NOT in a webview.

When does 'loadstop' occur, relative to events in the page such as jQuery's .ready or .load?  Is there a way to trap or trigger an event guaranteed to occur after 'loadstop' MIGHT be seen in the main App and a message sent and received by the webview's JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When does 'loadstop' occur, relative to events in the page such as jQuery's .ready or .load?

According to the documentation for the [loadstop](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-loadstop) event:

> Fired when all frame-level loads in a guest page (including all its subframes) have completed. This includes navigation within the current document as well as subframe document-level loads, **but does *not* include asynchronous resource loads.**

This would suggest it's more akin to jQuery's [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), which executes after the DOM tree is loaded, but before waiting for asset (.css, .js) downloads.

Keep an eye on that documentation page; it's already *much* improved since two weeks ago.

---

> Is there a way to trap or trigger an event guaranteed to occur after 'loadstop' MIGHT be seen in the main App and a message sent and received by the webview's JavaScript?

Your *manifest.json* declares your *my-app-main.js* background script (and your webview permission) which launches your *my-webview-wrapper.html* which includes your `<webview>` tag and also inlines some javascript (or sources a *my-webview-wrapper.js* file) that assigns event listeners to your webview via an `onload` function as such:

```
onload = function() {
  webview = document.getElementById("the-id-attribute-of-my-webview");
  webview.addEventListener("<EVENT>", function() {
    // the cool stuff you want to do
  }
}
```

`<EVENT>` can be any of the webview DOM events listed in the documentation I linked (including `loadstop`). Your main app shouldn't really care that any of this is happening. (It's async! It's javascript! It's magic!)

If you're still confused, just poke around Google's [webview sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/webview-samples/webview) on GitHub.

Comment: I am not sure where this onload code is placed - in the webview? So the webview can receive 'loadstop' at the same time as the main App? That might be handy, but the main App absolutely does care.  I am pre-loading a number of ads (pages in webviews) to display on a kiosk - they not only need images, JavaScript..., but they need to tell the main app when they are completely ready, including determining their own play length. Only then is the main app allowed to schedule them for display to users, or my clients are not happy.

Comment: Yeah the onload code is placed in (or linked from) the same embedder HTML page that calls the webview. For your specific problem, could you just make the webview hidden by default with CSS and then switch it to show from the loadstop callback function?

Comment: That is essentially what I am doing, but from your comments and the documentation, the loadstop event is happening too early for the webview - before async resources are loaded and before the webview's JavaScript can do its thing. Only the webview knows when this happens, so it needs to send a message or set a flag or do something, not the main app.  BTW, to work-around I have settled on having the main app poll the webviews every second - not the JavaScript async way but only a few lines of code in the end.

Comment: After a quick review of my code, specifically, the webview's page's JavaScript calls window.addEventListener('message', ...);                               so it can hear the main App.  But, will this be early enough to beat 'loadstop', or is there a potential that the Main App's response to it being lost in cyberspace?  I am afraid of a race condition bug.

Comment: Ooh that's a cool solution. I don't know enough about Javascript to say if that's a race condition, but it does _feel_ like it would be. Probably worth opening another question to ask that.